# MVC5: Refresh View on button (hyperlink) click?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When my MVC5 View loads, I am filling a list for a DropDown on the View and setting the View to only display model records that have a `[verified_date]` field value older than the `cutoff`, by default `3 Months`:

```
private InventoryTrackerContext db = new InventoryTrackerContext();

    // GET: VerifyAssets
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> intervalList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        intervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Month", Value = "Month" });
        intervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Day", Value = "Day" });
        intervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Year", Value = "Year" });
        var cutoffDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
        var iNV_Assets = db.INV_Assets.Where(i => i.verified_date < cutoffDate).Include(i => i.Location).Include(i => i.Manufacturer).Include(i => i.Model).Include(i => i.Status).Include(i => i.Type).Include(i => i.Vendor);
        ViewBag.intervalList = intervalList;
        return View(await iNV_Assets.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Now what I'm trying to implement, is allow users to specify an interval value and interval setting (values 1-31, and [Month], [Day], [Year]):

```
    @Html.DropDownList("NumberValueSelection", Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString() }))
    @Html.DropDownList("intervalList")
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm noDecoration" onclick="newCutoffDate()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"> REFRESH</span></a>
```

When users click the `[REFERSH]` button (hyperlink), I want to refresh the view based on user specifications:

**SCRIPT**:

```
    function newCutoffDate() {
        var _value = document.getElementById("NumberValueSelection").value;
        var _interval = document.getElementById("intervalList").value;
        var data = { value: _value, interval: _interval };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: '@Url.Action("NewCutoffDateInterval", "VerifyAssets")',
            data: data,
            success: function (resp) {
                alert("Sucess! Value: " + resp.value + " | Interval: " + resp.interval);
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                alert("Error! Value: " + resp.value + " | Interval: " + resp.interval);
            }
        })
    }
```

**CONTROLLER ACTION**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> NewCutoffDateInterval(int value, string interval)
    {
        var cutoffDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
        if (interval == "Month")
        {
            cutoffDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-value);
        }
        else
        {
            if (interval == "Day")
            {
                cutoffDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-value);
            }
            else
            {
                if (interval == "Year")
                {
                    cutoffDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-value);
                }
            }
        }

        var iNV_Assets = db.INV_Assets.Where(i => i.verified_date < cutoffDate).Include(i => i.Location).Include(i => i.Manufacturer).Include(i => i.Model).Include(i => i.Status).Include(i => i.Type).Include(i => i.Vendor);
        return View(await iNV_Assets.ToListAsync());
    }
```

This however is not working. When I click the `[REFRESH]` button (hyperlink), my function executes and my controller action gets called, but the View does not refresh. All that occurs is that I get a return of `"Error! Value: undefined | Interval: undefined".`undefined` makes sense considering I'm not returning anything, but why is the View not refreshing?

Comment: `HttpGet` for a `POST` request?

Comment: Just something I tried. Same result either way.

Comment: Why would the view refresh if the page isn't going anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure? Because I'm changing the query and returning the View?

Comment: but you're not doing anything with it.  That's being returned to the Javascript call

Comment: Ok, so after the return how do I refresh the View?

Comment: Instead of an ajax call just take the user back to the same page

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax({` doesn't modify the DOM nor the window.location.  It is an asynchronous request, and therefore happens "behind the scenes" so to speak.  **No navigation takes place, and the page/DOM is not modified without you explicitly doing so.**

If you want the entire page to refresh, you have a couple of options.

**Navigation via standard href**

Make your link point to a valid `href` so when they user clicks it, they will be navigated.  Use javascript as the user modifies selections to modify the `href` encoding parameters as query string values.  You get the "Refresh" effect just by pointing the URL to the same page, but dynamically updating the href as the user makes selections before hitting refresh.  When the user clicks the link, the controller should parse the parameters, and return the same page with new filters applied.

`<a href='/VerifyAssets/NewCutoffDateInterval?someParameter=someValue'>Refresh</a>`

**Navigation via window.location**

Keep you `<a>` as is, but modify your javascript such that instead of making an ajax request, you build a URL as described above, and set it as window.location, causing the page to navigate to the new URL:

```
// assume you build part after ? dynamically
var url = '/VerifyAssets/NewCutoffDateInterval?someParameter=someValue';
window.location.href = url;
```

**Refreshing partial page**

If you create an action that returns a partial view, you can refresh a portion of the page by replacing the content of some element with what is returned:

```
   success: function (resp) {
           $('#idOfSomeDiv').html(resp); // replace contents with returned
   },
```

If the request points to a partial view, then `resp` will be the HTML fragment representing the partial view, and we need to take that and insert it somewhere on the page, which is what `$('#idOfSomeDiv').html(resp);` does.

There's lots of nuances to each of these approaches that's covered pretty thoroughly elsewhere, so I'm not going to get into that.  Some versions of jquery for example require you parse the response before setting it in the DOM.  I'll leave it up to you to research your method of choice further.

Comment: If I navigate through window.location as above, how do I implement the change? I can build the URL to have my parameter values, but then how do I get it to recognize to load only those with say a `[verification_date]` older than 5 days from current date?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic That's a separate question dealing with model binding. MVC treats form input `name`'s the same it does query string names, so to bind to `NewCutoffDateInterval(int value, string interval)` you would send `/VerifyAssets/NewCutoffDateInterval?value=5&interval=Day`.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a `ViewResult` to a Javascript call.  This won't refresh the view.  The better option is to make your existing Controller route an HTTP GET that your refresh link reuses and passes the parameters set in your interface as query string parameters.

**EDIT**:  When I've done this before, I've taken the HTML being returned from async route, and appended it into the DOM.  This is different because you're looking to replace the DOM, but it's the same basic idea.

Here's some example Javascript that appends AJAX retrieved HTML into the page

```
window.EditableList = function (containerSelector) {
var $container = $(containerSelector);
var $list = $container.find("ol").eq(0);
$container
    .off(".editable-list")
    .on("click.editable-list", "a.add-editor-row", function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: e.target.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $list.append(html);
                ShowHideIcons($("#question-style-dropdown").val());
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
    .on("click.editable-list", "a.delete-editor-row", function (e) {
        $(e.target).parents('li.editor-row').remove();
        return false;
    });
};
```

sample controller action

```
public ActionResult AddFragment()
{
    var viewModel = new FragmentViewModel(parameters);
    return PartialView("Fragment", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Have an example? That's the route I initially tried.